# Handling Grid Columns using sahi scripting

Tags: sahi

Situation is - We are automating a test case, where in the user click on Addrow icon on the grid, by doing so a row is added. User will have enter value in the first 2 columns, 3 column is a drop down. We were able to script the test case and when we give run, the value entered in the first 2 columns is not getting displayed. But if we give a wait time of 1sec we are able to see the value entered in the first 2 columns of the row. how to display value in the column without providing the waittime using sahi? Please suggest.

```
    include("../Base/Include.sah");


Testcase Desccription: Dealer-Issuer Grid-Custom Issuers-Add Row
*/
//
//_click(_submit("Custom Issuers"));
//
//_wait(4000);
_click(_submit("Add Row"));
//_doubleClick(_cell("current highlight[1]"))
// _setValue(_cell("current highlight[1]"), "sri-ci-3");

//issuer name
_click(_row("5"));
//_doubleClick(_cell("current highlight[1]"));
_wait(1000);
_setValue(_textarea(0), "Auto-1");
_wait(1000);
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please share the code which is not working. Otherwise we can only guess.  For comparison, you wouldn't ask a mechanic to fix your car without looking at it! :-)

Comment: Please edit the question, don't include code in comments - it's impossible to read properly and some people might miss it.

Comment: Okay, have removed my comment, appended the code in the discussion window. Thanks

Comment: Use assertions or conditional wait statements. You can find the docs here: http://sahipro.com/docs/sahi-apis/assertions.html